# Create a typeValidation that will take jsonPath and type, this should check the path is of same type or not

Tags: java, json, validation

create a typeValidation that will take jsonPath and type, this should check the path is of same type or not??

validateByType(jsonString, pathString, typeString)
validateByValue(jsonString, pathString, valueString)

Implementation will use jayway Jsonpath Validation  to get the value of a give path and then we have to find whether it is same or not

```
{
    "store": {
        "book": [
            {
                "category": "reference",
                "author": "Nigel Rees",
                "title": "Sayings of the Century",
                "price": 8.95
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Evelyn Waugh",
                "title": "Sword of Honour",
                "price": 12.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "Herman Melville",
                "title": "Moby Dick",
                "isbn": "0-553-21311-3",
                "price": 8.99
            },
            {
                "category": "fiction",
                "author": "J. R. R. Tolkien",
                "title": "The Lord of the Rings",
                "isbn": "0-395-19395-8",
                "price": 22.99
            }
        ],
        "bicycle": {
            "color": "red",
            "price": 19.95
        }
    },
    "expensive": 10
}
```

I need to validateByType(jsonString, pathString, typeString)
validateByValue(jsonString, pathString, valueString) by using above Json code??

Can you please help me in this??
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: what's your goal from JsonPath and JsonType?

Comment: By using above code, I need to validateByType(jsonString, pathString, typeString) validateByValue(jsonString, pathString, valueString) by using above Json code??

Comment: add an example please.